# Updating element property in scala list buffer

Tags: scala

I have a listbuffer of events Animals. I am trying to update one of those properties.However, when using `update` it updates the whole element. Is there a way to update a particualr property? I'd want to update the `owner` for example.

```
import java.util.UUID

case class Car(model: String, owner: String)

var cars = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Car]()

var car1 = Car("honda", "John")
var car2 = Car("chevy", "Xavier")
var car3 = Car("subaru", "Mario")

cars += car1
cars += car2
cars += car3

def generateRandomGuid(numOfTenants: Int) = {
  List.tabulate(numOfTenants)(_ => UUID.randomUUID().toString())
}

val ownerList = generateRandomGuid(3)

for(newowner <- ownerList) {
    for(eventIdx <- 0 to cars.length-1) {
      //cars.update(eventIdx, newowner)
     cars(eventIdx).owner = newowner 
    }  
}
```

Update1:
updated to using var for the different cars and the list buffer to `Car` however, i still cannot reassign because  `error: reassignment to val cars(eventIdx).owner = newowner`

Comment: To update a particular field, you don't have to do anything to your `ListBuffer` (which should be a `ListBuffer[Car]`, btw). You'd have to mark `owner` with `var`, and then you can do `cars(eventIdx).owner = newOwner`

Comment: After updating that, as well as using 'var' I still cannot update the field because of reassignment to `val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that objects in Scala are immutable by default. The error you are getting (`error: reassignment to val cars(eventIdx).owner = newowner`) means that you cannot update the `owner` property of a car, because properties are immutable by default. As @nrvaller mentioned in their comment, you can declare the `owner` property as a variable.

Comment: I think you meant "immutable" instead of "constants" (and you did use "immutable" the first time)